# EFCore Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am accepting 3 fields from a user. All 3 fields are mandatory to be entered. Look at the entity configuration below - all 3 fields in the `EntityConfiguration` has been marked as `Required`.

This works perfectly when I am Saving a new record to the database. However, now I require to Update an entry. In that case If I ONLY want to update the `UserName`, and `Password` - there's an exception thrown because `Age` can't be `Null`. How can I resolved this ?

```
InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Age', table 'DBFFFF.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

CODE

```
public class User
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder.Property(c => c.UserName)
                       .IsRequired(true);

        builder.Property(c => c.Password )
            .IsRequired(true);

        builder.Property(c => c.Age )
            .IsRequired(true); 
    }
}
    public async Task<string> UpdateUs(User u)
    {
        _dbCont.Update(u);
        await _dbCont.SaveChangesAsync();
        return "ok";
    }
```

Comment: How are you updating the entity? That code is more relevant than the configuration

Comment: I have updated my code. Please have a look

Comment: `_dbCont.Update(u);` <-- You probably don't need to do this. Anyway, this is also the cause of the issue because your `User u` object has an un-set `Age` property which EF interprets as a _changed property_ and so thinks the value should be stored as `NULL` (also, you should store DoB as a `date` in your database, not an `Age` value, because a person's age changes every year).

Comment: This is not problem, what you send, EF updates it. I mean you are sending this value as a null and it understand that you want to update this field as a null and I think it is so normal process.

Comment: `builder.Property(c => c.Password )` -- **DO NOT STORE YOUR USERS' PASSWORDS AS PLAINTEXT!!!!!** You must hash and salt them instead.

Comment: @Dai Yes. It is Salted and hashed.

Comment: Then why are you using a single `string Password` value instead of `byte[] PasswordHash` and `byte[] PasswordSalt`?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for pointing out. I will make that change. BTW. I have only included part of the Entity class here that I thought was relevant to this problem. Anyway , I didn't know that I could use byte[] as the datatype to store the password hash.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    public async Task<string> UpdateUs(User u)
    {
        _dbCont.Update(u);
        await _dbCont.SaveChangesAsync();
        return "ok";
    }
```

I assume that your call-site for `UpdateUs` looks like this:

```
User u = new User()
{
    Id = 123,
    UserName = "foobar"
};

await UpdateUs(u);
```

- Note that the above code *does not set any values* for `Age` and `Password`

  - **AND YOU MUST NOT STORE USERS' PASSWORDS AS PLAINTEXT!**
- ...but then your code calls `DbContext.Update`...

  - ...which basically tells EF that "this object `u` now represents the current-state of the entity with `Id = 123` *including* the fact that `Age = null`", which is *not* what you want.

    - I assume what you actually want is for EF to only consider the `UserName` property as updated and to ignore the other non-key properties (`Password` and `Age`) which have not yet been set.
- Also, I get the feeling that you're using your entity classes as mutable view-models (e.g. in ASP.NET or WPF). *You should not do that* because an entity object represents persisted business-data state, it does not represent in-memory mutable UI state.

  - Also, view-models need additional annotations and members that entity types don't have. For example, an "Edit User" view-model needs two password fields ("New password" and "Confirm new password"), this is why we have separate classes for view-models *even when they have the same members as an entity class*.

---

Anyway, the correct solution for this (*assuming* that you still want to use your `class User` as an internal DTO), is to use `Attach` and set `IsModified` on the properties you're updating.

Like so:

```
    public async Task< UpdateUserAsync(User u)
    {
        // Preconditions:
        if( u is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(u));
        if( u.Id == default ) throw new ArgumentException( message: "User's Id is not set.", paramName: nameof(u) );

        // 

        this.dbContext.Users.Attach( u );

        var entry = this.dbContext.Entry( u );
        if( u.UserName != null ) entry.Property( x => x.UserName ).IsModified = true;
        if( u.Age      != null ) entry.Property( x => x.Age      ).IsModified = true;

        this.dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; // <-- Only do this if necessary.

        Int32 rowCount = await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        if( rowCount != 1 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "No rows (or too many rows) were updated." );
    }
```

Comment: Woah Thanks. In addition to the problem I had, there's more detail here. Thank you I have learnt a lot from your detailed answer.

Comment: Just a quick question. Is there a way to find what What properties of the Objects are Null and set IsModified - true; ? Like for example at times Age can be null and some other times Password or UserName can be null. Is there a way to detect these as well ?

Comment: @Illep If `Age` can be `null` then why is it marked as `Required` (i.e. `NOT NULL`)? As I said, you should _not_ be using Entity Classes as view-models. It sounds like you should create a separate `class UserDetailsForm` and write a method that maps that to (and from) your `User` entity object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful answer. You can ignore the specific field(s) when you do update

```
public async Task<string> UpdateUser(User u)
{
    _dbCont.Update(u);
    _dbCont.Entry(u).Property(x => x.Age).IsModified = false;
    await _dbCont.SaveChangesAsync();
    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

With the below configuration, you are making Age field not nullable.

```
builder.Property(c => c.Age ).IsRequired(true);
```

Remove `IsRequired(true)`; Configuration should be as below.

```
builder.Property(c => c.Age );
```

Comment: I want to keep it as Not Nullable. This is very useful for me when I am saving records. Is there a way to temporarily enable fields Nullable ?

Comment: The OP _doesn't_ want to make the column `NULL`able, they want to stop EF doing `UPDATE SET Age = NULL`.

Comment: @Dai Yes. Exactly. This is what I require to do